# How do I get eslint to give an error when ES6 javascript features are used?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to ensure that my output only contains "vanilla" javascript and does not contain new features (like `const`, `map()`, `=>` etc.).

This is to ensure that the code still works on legacy browsers.

Comment: `map` is not a new feature. And it's not syntax so you hardly can detect it.

Comment: Just use an ES5 parser and see where it barfs?